# MVC File upload with Custom Validation is null

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am uploading and image and verifying its validity as per this post here: 
[How to validate uploaded file in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6388812/how-to-validate-uploaded-file-in-asp-net-mvc)
However, my example differs slightly because I am not just receiving the file, I am also receiving some properties for my model. However, my validator always fires, I debugged and found that my file is always null, so validator always fires back 'false'. I don't understand why, my input in view seems to be correct. Any ideas?

```
namespace PhotoManagement.Models
{
public class Photo
{
    public virtual int PhotoId { get; set; }
    public virtual int ClientId { get; set; }
    public virtual string PhotoDescription { get; set; }
    [ImageValidation(ErrorMessage="Please select a PNG/JPEG image smaller than 10 MB")]
    [NotMapped]
    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
}
}
```

---

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(Photo photo)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Photos.Add(photo);
            db.SaveChanges();
            // File upload occurs now
            var FilePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/" + photo.ClientId), photo.PhotoId.ToString());
            photo.File.SaveAs(FilePath);
            return RedirectToAction("Create");
        }
        else return View();
    }
```

---

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>Photo for @Session["Name"]</legend>

    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.Hidden("ClientId",(int)Session["UserId"])
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PhotoDescription)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PhotoDescription)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PhotoDescription)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.File)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <input type="file" name="File" id="File"/>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.File)
    </div>
```

Comment: see if you can upload file at least to see if model binding is correct . then apply server side validation .

Comment: How big is the file you're trying to upload? See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10856240/asp-mvc-file-upload-httppostedfilebase-is-null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a **wrong overload** of the `Html.BeginForm` helper.

The correct call is this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{

}
```

You were calling:

```
Html.BeginForm(object routeValues)
```

instead of:

```
Html.BeginForm(
    string actionName, 
    string controllerName, 
    FormMethod method, 
    object htmlAttributes
)
```

Look at the generated markup in your browser and you will see the fundamental difference.

Comment: You are my hero man, I searched for hours on how to fix this yesturday. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
public ActionResult Create(Photo photo)
```

Try

```
public ActionResult Create(Photo photo, HttpPostedFileBase file)
```

**EDIT**: Don't forget to set the HTTP method to POST in the view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

Comment: How would this help? He already has a property called `File` of type `HttpPostedFileBase` on his `Photo` model.

Comment: I had this problem in the past, I fixed it by doing like this. Don't ask me why....

Comment: No, this cannot possibly have fixed the problem :-)

Answer (score -1):

The file in Model will always give you null. In order to get file :

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(UserViewModel model, 
FormCollection formCollection, HttpPostedFileBase file){

     /* Your code here */
    if(file==null)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("NoFile", "Upload File");
    }
}
```

Here **HttpPostedFileBase file** will give you the complete object of file uploaded. You can have check condition on the object file. Don't forget to add the below mentioned validation message in view.

```
@Html.ValidationMessage("NoFile")
```

Comment: Oh no, how many times you will include this `file` argument? He already has it as part of his Photo view model. It's completely redundant to have this file argument and even more completely redundant to have this FormCollection argument.

Comment: I saw Shalin's method online a lot, but in my case it doesn't apply because then I cannot use the model attribute to verify.