# Object reference not set when trying to send file with form in MVC.NET

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, reference

I have a `@Html.BeginForm()` which is binden to a ViewModel named CreateQuestionViewModel. This ViewModel looks like this:

```
public class CreateQuestionModel
{
  public Question Question { get; set; }
  public List<int> PoliticianIds { get; set; }
  public List<int> TopicIds { get; set; }
  public HttpPostedFile File { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to submit this form and create a Question instance, a list if PoliticianIds and a list of Topicids everything works. When I try and add a file using `<input type="file" name="File"/>` I get an error at a completely unrelated line in the Create.cshtml, the line where I go through a foreach to populate a `<select>` list. This is how the form in my Create.cshtml looks:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>Vraag</legend>

    <div class="general-question">
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Question.GeneralQuestion, "Algemene Vraag")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Question.GeneralQuestion, new { @class = "general-question-edit" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Question.GeneralQuestion)
        </div>
    </div>


    <div id="geadresseerde-politici">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PoliticianIds, "Geadresseerde Politici (maximum 5):")

        <select name="PoliticianIds" id="polDrop" multiple style="width: 500px">
            @foreach (var par in ((List<Party>)ViewBag.Parties))
            {
                <optgroup label="@par.Name (@par.FullName)">

                @foreach (var pol in ((List<Politician>)par.Politicians))
                {
                    @(ViewBag.CurrPol = pol)
                    <option value="@pol.UserId">@pol.FirstName @pol.LastName (@pol.Party.Name)</option>
                }

                </optgroup>
            }
        </select>

    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Question.Explanation, "Extra Uitleg")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Question.Explanation, new { @class = "explanation-textarea-edit" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Question.Explanation)
    </div>        

    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TopicIds, "Kies je thema's (maximum 2):")
        <select name="TopicIds" id="topDrop" multiple style="width: 500px">
            @foreach (var top in ((List<Topic>)ViewBag.TopIds).Where(top => top.MainTopic == null))
            {
                <option value="@top.TopicId" class="optionGroup">@top.Name</option>
                foreach (var subTopic in top.SubTopics)
                {
                    <option value="@subTopic.TopicId" class="optionChild">@subTopic.Name</option>
                }
            }
        </select>
    </div>

    @*<div>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TopicIds, "Kies je thema's (maximum 2):")
        @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.TopicIds, (MultiSelectList)ViewBag.Topics, new { @id = "select2select", @style = "width: 500px"})
    </div>*@


    @Html.Label("Voeg bestanden toe:")
    <input type="file" name="createQuestionModel.File"/>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Post!" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}
```

When I use this to create a Question everything works. When I try and add an image I get the following error at the `@foreach(...)` line:

[image: ObjectReference not set...]

The error is in Dutch but translates to: "The object reference is not set to an instance of an object".

I have no idea what could be wrong because I don't get this error when I don't add a file, and there is no link between adding a file and this select list...

Here is my Create post method in my controller:

```
public ActionResult Create(CreateQuestionModel createQuestionModel)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    if (createQuestionModel.File != null && createQuestionModel.File.ContentLength > 0)
    {
      String fileName = Path.GetFileName(createQuestionModel.File.FileName);

      String path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName);

      createQuestionModel.File.SaveAs(path);
    }

    int id = WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;
    manager.CreateQuestion(createQuestionModel.Question, id, createQuestionModel.PoliticianIds, createQuestionModel.TopicIds);
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Question", new { page = 1});
  }

  return View(createQuestionModel);
}
```

I hope someone can help me because I am absolutely puzzled...

**EDIT**

My Create Get action as requested:

```
public ActionResult Create(int userId = -1, int topicId = -1)
{
  ViewBag.polIds = manager.GetAllPoliticians();
  //ViewBag.Politicians = new MultiSelectList(manager.GetAllPoliticians(), "UserId", "FirstName");
  if (userId > -1)
  {
    ViewBag.AddressedPolitcian = manager.GetPolitician(userId);
  }
  ViewBag.AddressedId = userId;

  ViewBag.TopIds = manager.GetAllTopics();
  //ViewBag.Topics = new MultiSelectList(manager.GetAllTopics(), "TopicId", "Name");
  if (topicId > -1)
  {
    ViewBag.AddressedTopic = manager.GetTopic(topicId);
  }
  ViewBag.AddressedTopicId = topicId;

  ViewBag.Parties = manager.GetAllParties();

  return View();
}
```

Comment: please post you get action as well

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer in this stackoverflow thread I didn't find before: [ASP MVC FIle Upload HttpPostedFileBase is Null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10856240/asp-mvc-file-upload-httppostedfilebase-is-null) . basically I entered max size in web.config and use HttpPostedFileBase instead of HttpPostedFile AND apparently you can't use file in a ViewModel so you need to enter it as a separate parameter in your Create POST method!

Comment: post your solution code as well for other people help

Comment: That error just disappeared so it was some kind of false message. I'll post my solution when I have time ;) Thanks for your help!

Comment: one thing you tlod HttpPostedFileBase and other was setting enctype = "multipart/form-data" in form